# gridview CommandField Update & cancel image coming Up down on IE

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i am using Gridview.

my code is:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvReceivers" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    BackColor="LightGoldenrodYellow" BorderColor="Tan" BorderWidth="1px" 
    CellPadding="2" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="None"
    OnRowEditing="RowEditing" Font-Size="Medium" 
    OnSelectedIndexChanging="gvReceivers_SelectedIndexChanging" 
    onrowcancelingedit="gvReceivers_RowCancelingEdit" 
    onrowdeleting="gvReceivers_RowDeleting" 
            onrowupdating="gvReceivers_RowUpdating">
    <FooterStyle BackColor="Tan" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" ButtonType="Image"
                CancelImageUrl="~/Images/Cancel.png" UpdateImageUrl="~/Images/save.png"
                EditImageUrl="~/images/Edit.png" ItemStyle-Width="25px"
                UpdateText="Update" CancelText="Cancel" />
    <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="true" 
                DeleteImageUrl="~/Images/delete.png" ButtonType="Image"
        ItemStyle-Width="25px" />
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="imgSelect" 
                        CommandName="Select" AlternateText="Select"
            ImageUrl="~/Images/allowed.png" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

now, i click on edit image. update & cancel images & Event are coming.but issue is on IE Update & Cancel image coming Up & Down. it's working fine on Mozila & chrome.check below image.

[image]

Comment: Please change your width Pixel to %

Answer (score 2):

It's simple just add  ItemStyle-Wrap="false" in your column.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have not given any width for `ItemTemplate`, you can take two separate `ItemTemplate` or you can also work with single.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ColumnHeader">
       <EditItemTemplate>
            //You controls
       </EditItemTemplate>
    <ItemStyle Width="30%" />
```

**Edit **
You can follow this [link](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/02/how-to-inserteditupdate-and-delete-data.html) and update code accordingly. If get stuck any where then you can ask me. Here we can guide you but the main task you have to do your self.

Answer (score 0):

As Dorel Domocos suggested, I managed to solve the line break using the **ItemStyle Wrap** in the *CommandField*.

For example:

```
<asp:CommandField ButtonType="Image" ShowEditButton="True" EditImageUrl="~/images/edit.png" CancelImageUrl="~/images/cancel.png" UpdateImageUrl="~/images/update.png" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" >
    <ItemStyle Wrap="False" Width="48px"></ItemStyle>
</asp:CommandField>
```

It can be either on the *CommandField* with the attribute `ItemStyle-Wrap="false"`, or with its *ItemStyle* element with `Wrap="False"` attribute.

---

The generated result has the `white-space:nowrap;` CSS style, having the following when being in Edit mode:

```
<td style="width:48px;white-space:nowrap;">
    <input type="image" name="GridView1$ctl02$ctl00" src="images/update.png" alt="Update">
    &nbsp;
    <input type="image" src="images/cancel.png" alt="Cancel" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('GridView1','Cancel$0');return false;">
</td>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -3):

```
<asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="imgSelect" 
                        CommandName="Select" AlternateText="Select"
            ImageUrl="~/Images/allowed.png" />
        </ItemTemplate>
 <ItemStyle Width="30%" />
    </asp:TemplateField>
```